# Textures look blurry when looking from a distance with Three.js

Tags: three.js

In my game that uses Three.js, my textures look blurry when I go further away from them.
Due to the nature of my 16-bit retro style, I must not have anything blurry.

Any idea what I could do to solve this? I create my textures like this:

```
var texture  = new THREE.Texture( image,
  new THREE.UVMapping(),
  THREE.RepeatWrapping,
  THREE.RepeatWrapping,
  THREE.NearestFilter,
  THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter );
```

[image]

If I select NearestFilter for both, the result looks rather ugly and too sharp:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used NearestMipMapLinearFilter instead of LinearMipMapLinearFilter  and the result looks acceptable:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would give anisotropic filtering a shot, but "no" bluriness is not really possible.

Here's an example:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_texture_anisotropy.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Just tried it, but unfortunately it stretches my 16-bit textures and blurs them completely, so its not useful for my situation :(

Comment: Hmm :/... Even with 16 samples?

Comment: Well, I used getMaxAnisotropy(), the same which was used in the demo you posted. So yes.